# regexp_extract is getting spaces

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have this sample data to test `regexp_extract` function.

```
message_txt="test 9341Come Products Preferred*TEST*TEST, the mfg SYSTEM, paid18.26 toward the"
message_txt="mfg of TR tt 100 test, paid $861.82 toward your "
message_txt="TEST 0.015% , paid $1119.00toward your "
```

I need to extract the numeric value between "paid" and "toward", i.e. 18.26, 861.82 and 1119.00. I execute the below statement

```
regexp_extract(col("message_txt"),"(?i)paid\\s+(.*?)\\s+(?i)toward",1)
```

... but getting only spaces.

Comment: Replace the "." With "[^\s]", or even better something like [\d\.\$]

Comment: \$ is giving error.

Comment: regexp_extract(col("message_txt"),"(?i)paid\\s+[\d\.\$]\\s+(?i)toward",1)  - This is not working

Comment: regexp_extract(col("message_comment_txt"),"(?i)paid\\s+([\d\.\$]*?)\\s+(?i)toward",1) -- This is also not working

Comment: Sorry it's Scala, you need to escape \ (e.g. [^\\s])

Answer (score 1):

I don't know `regexp_extract()` but it looks to me like...

- You don't want `$` in your results, so you need to move that outside of the capture group.
- There aren't always spaces before/after the target, so `\\s` needs to be optional.
- There's no point in having a 2nd `(?i)`.
- It's usually better to describe exactly what's permitted in the capture group.

Try something like: `"(?i)paid\\s*\\$?([\\d.]+)\\s*toward"`